# PHP - how to get specific value of curl response

Tags: php, xml, curl, xml-parsing

I am using curl method to get response from an API. It did return a xml response.

The response return a set of strings which I could not get the exact value that I want.

These are my codes:

```
$url = 'someurlwithGETparameter';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

for example:

```
< foods >
     < chinese > Shark Fin </ chinese>
     < japanese > Sushi </ japanese>
< /foods >
```

I would like to get Chinese food "Shark Fin" and put it in a variable.

```
$chineseFood = $somethinglike['chinese'];
```

So when I echo $chineseFood, I will get "Shark Fin".

Please help. Just started CURL today and I am not really familiar with CURL

Thanks a lot =)

Comment: If the return result is XML you can parse it with some of the PHP xml parsers as SimpleXML

Comment: Yes, I believe that's the thing I need. =D

Comment: Making light of the controversial shark fins as a food. Sharks are being hunted to extinction as a delicacy. :( -1

Answer (score 0):

This is not a curl problem, this is an issue of parsing XML which is what your API returns by the looks of it. A simple solution is using one of the standard XML parsers PHP provides:

1. [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)
2. [Dom Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

PHP offers more (see [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) in the manual), but these two will suffice. The simple xml parser is exactly what is says. A simple parser. It works on basic stuff but will be less ideal when XML using namespaces and other "complicated" stuff is fed into it. The DOM parser can basically handle all you want.

In your specific case, curl_exec will return this XML I presume. If this is the case than you could do something along these lines:

```
// all curl stuff here
$xmlString = curl_exec($ch);
$XmlElement = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
$chineseFoods = $XmlElement->chinese;
```

You can call `$XmlElement->chinese` directly since foods will be interpreted as root node of the XML "document"

Comment: I believe this is the thing I need, but what if the output is something like < chinese foodname="shark fin"></ chinese>

Comment: Then you will need to have a look at the DomDocument set of classes. Those are betters suited. In  that case we're talking getting an attribute of a node. When using DomDocument you can get Nodes by tagname. Once you have those nodes which are http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php objects you can get attributes of those. Check http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php and read up on the DomNodeList it returns. That list in turn contains DomNode objects.

Answer (score 0):

Having never used `SimpleXML` I can't comment on how to use or how easy it really is but as @hoppa mentioned you can use the built-in Dom Parsing functions built around `DOMDocument`

```
$food=array();
$data="
<foods>
     <chinese foodtype='soup'>Shark Fin</chinese>
     <japanese foodtype='fish'>Sushi</japanese>
     <italian foodtype='wheat'>Pasta</italian>
     <british foodtype='delicious'>fish n chips</british>
</foods>";

/* Try to prevent errors from being displayed */
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );

/* Create the reference to the DOMDocument and set some properties */
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->standalone=true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->substituteEntities=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->formatOutput=false;
/* Load the XML data */
$dom->loadXML( $data );
$parse_errs=serialize( libxml_get_last_error() );

libxml_clear_errors();

/* Get the root node and then iterate through it's children */
$foods=$dom->getElementsByTagName('foods')->item(0);
foreach( $foods->childNodes as $i => $node ) {

    if( $node->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE ){
        /* Elements can have attributes, use this methodology to find and get attributes */
        $foodtype=$node->hasAttribute('foodtype') ? $node->getAttribute('foodtype') : '';
        /* Do whatever you want with the tag or data etc */
        echo $node->tagName.' '.$node->nodeValue.' '.$foodtype.BR;
        /* You could store in an array for later use for example */
        $food[ $node->tagName ]=(object)array( 'type'=>$foodtype, 'value'=>$node->nodeValue );
    }
}

$dom=null;

/* Later on.... */
$type='chinese';
echo 'From the array: '.$food[ $type ]->type.' '.$food[ $type ]->value;
```

Answer (score 0):

In DOM you can use Xpath to fetch specific values and nodes:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<foods>
     <chinese foodtype='soup'>Shark Fin</chinese>
     <japanese foodtype='fish'>Sushi</japanese>
     <italian foodtype='wheat'>Pasta</italian>
     <british foodtype='delicious'>fish n chips</british>
</foods>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

var_dump(
  // the text content of an element node
  $xpath->evaluate('string(/foods/chinese)'),
  // the value of an attribute node
  $xpath->evaluate('string(/foods/chinese/@foodtype)')
);
```

Output:

```
string(9) "Shark Fin"
string(4) "soup"
```

If the result is not cast into a scalar (string, number, boolean) it will always be a node list, that you can iterate using foreach:

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/foods/*[@foodtype = "fish"]') as $food) {
  var_dump(
    [
      'name' => $food->textContent,
      'group' => $food->localName,
      'type' => $food->getAttribute('foodtype')
    ]
  );
}
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(5) "Sushi"
  ["group"]=>
  string(8) "japanese"
  ["type"]=>
  string(4) "fish"
}
```

The returned objects are DOMNode instances, the actual class depends on the node type.

Answer (score -1):

CURL is mechanism utilized to perform HTTP request/response.
According to above mentioned description the CURL request returns response in XML format.

Please try executing following code snippet to parse XML document.

```
<?php 
/** 
 * xml2array() will convert the given XML text to an array in the XML structure. 
 * Link: http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/xml2array/ 
 * Arguments : $contents - The XML text 
 *                $get_attributes - 1 or 0. If this is 1 the function will get the attributes as well as the tag values - this results in a different array structure in the return value.
 *                $priority - Can be 'tag' or 'attribute'. This will change the way the resulting array sturcture. For 'tag', the tags are given more importance.
 * Return: The parsed XML in an array form. Use print_r() to see the resulting array structure. 
 * Examples: $array =  xml2array(file_get_contents('feed.xml')); 
 *              $array =  xml2array(file_get_contents('feed.xml', 1, 'attribute')); 
 */ 
function xml2array($contents, $get_attributes=1, $priority = 'tag') { 
    if(!$contents) return array(); 

    if(!function_exists('xml_parser_create')) { 
        //print "'xml_parser_create()' function not found!"; 
        return array(); 
    } 

    //Get the XML parser of PHP - PHP must have this module for the parser to work 
    $parser = xml_parser_create(''); 
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, "UTF-8"); # http://minutillo.com/steve/weblog/2004/6/17/php-xml-and-character-encodings-a-tale-of-sadness-rage-and-data-loss 
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0); 
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1); 
    xml_parse_into_struct($parser, trim($contents), $xml_values); 
    xml_parser_free($parser); 

    if(!$xml_values) return;//Hmm... 

    //Initializations 
    $xml_array = array(); 
    $parents = array(); 
    $opened_tags = array(); 
    $arr = array(); 

    $current = &$xml_array; //Refference 

    //Go through the tags. 
    $repeated_tag_index = array();//Multiple tags with same name will be turned into an array 
    foreach($xml_values as $data) { 
        unset($attributes,$value);//Remove existing values, or there will be trouble 

        //This command will extract these variables into the foreach scope 
        // tag(string), type(string), level(int), attributes(array). 
        extract($data);//We could use the array by itself, but this cooler. 

        $result = array(); 
        $attributes_data = array(); 

        if(isset($value)) { 
            if($priority == 'tag') $result = $value; 
            else $result['value'] = $value; //Put the value in a assoc array if we are in the 'Attribute' mode
        } 

        //Set the attributes too. 
        if(isset($attributes) and $get_attributes) { 
            foreach($attributes as $attr => $val) { 
                if($priority == 'tag') $attributes_data[$attr] = $val; 
                else $result['attr'][$attr] = $val; //Set all the attributes in a array called 'attr' 
            } 
        } 

        //See tag status and do the needed. 
        if($type == "open") {//The starting of the tag '<tag>' 
            $parent[$level-1] = &$current; 
            if(!is_array($current) or (!in_array($tag, array_keys($current)))) { //Insert New tag 
                $current[$tag] = $result; 
                if($attributes_data) $current[$tag. '_attr'] = $attributes_data; 
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1; 

                $current = &$current[$tag]; 

            } else { //There was another element with the same tag name 

                if(isset($current[$tag][0])) {//If there is a 0th element it is already an array 
                    $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]] = $result; 
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++; 
                } else {//This sectio$data = cn will make the value an array if multiple tags with the same name appear together
                    $current[$tag] = array($current[$tag],$result);//This will combine the existing item and the new item together to make an array
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 2; 

                    if(isset($current[$tag.'_attr'])) { //The attribute of the last(0th) tag must be moved as well
                        $current[$tag]['0_attr'] = $current[$tag.'_attr']; 
                        unset($current[$tag.'_attr']); 
                    } 

                } 
                $last_item_index = $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]-1; 
                $current = &$current[$tag][$last_item_index]; 
            } 

        } elseif($type == "complete") { //Tags that ends in 1 line '<tag />' 
            //See if the key is already taken. 
            if(!isset($current[$tag])) { //New Key 
                $current[$tag] = $result; 
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1; 
                if($priority == 'tag' and $attributes_data) $current[$tag. '_attr'] = $attributes_data;

            } else { //If taken, put all things inside a list(array) 
                if(isset($current[$tag][0]) and is_array($current[$tag])) {//If it is already an array... 

                    // ...push the new element into that array. 
                    $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]] = $result; 

                    if($priority == 'tag' and $get_attributes and $attributes_data) { 
                        $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] . '_attr'] = $attributes_data; 
                    } 
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++; 

                } else { //If it is not an array... 
                    $current[$tag] = array($current[$tag],$result); //...Make it an array using using the existing value and the new value
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1; 
                    if($priority == 'tag' and $get_attributes) { 
                        if(isset($current[$tag.'_attr'])) { //The attribute of the last(0th) tag must be moved as well

                            $current[$tag]['0_attr'] = $current[$tag.'_attr']; 
                            unset($current[$tag.'_attr']); 
                        } 

                        if($attributes_data) { 
                            $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] . '_attr'] = $attributes_data; 
                        } 
                    } 
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++; //0 and 1 index is already taken 
                } 
            } 

        } elseif($type == 'close') { //End of tag '</tag>' 
            $current = &$parent[$level-1]; 
        } 
    } 

    return($xml_array); 
}  
    $response_array=xml2array($response);
```

Information from curl response can be easily retrieved from response array variable.